# Creating An extension installer for a cms using laravel 5.3

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, content-management-system

Hello So I am creating basic cms which is in laravel 5.3 that I want to use for a lot of my sites I work on in the future. Currently, I have created the core back-end with creation of articles and cateogries and a settings handler. However I want to the rest of the back end features to be installable like an extension for other CMS. All i would have to do is drop a Zip folder with a json or xml file to state some basic info and then it will automatically create the routes and templates that maybe needed. An example of what I want is a media manager extension. This could be what the json file would look like:

```
{
    "ExtensionName":"Media Manager",
    "Alias":"media-manager",
    //Routes in the admin area. First is the route the second is the class
    "RoutesAdmin":[{"media/manager":"MediaManager"},{"media/manager/new":"MediaNew"}],
    "RoutesFront":'[{"/img/{imgName}":"ImageGet"}]
}
```

This is only a quick example of what I think should happen. But i want all this to be added with me needing to code it over and over again from one site to the other. What is the best way of handling this.
However this is up to change depending. Please redirect me to tutorials if needed. But I am having troubles figuring this out.

Thank you

Comment: Develop them as composer packages. Then all you need to do is add it to your `composer.json` and `composer update` to have it working. You can even create some sort of UI for doing that if you dislike CLI. No need to invent your own JSON format, no need for.. well, anything really, you "just" need to develop actual business logic and let composer do the rest, it even supports versioning etc.

Comment: Ok but how do I manage adding the routes and other elements like that?

Comment: You're a programmer, be creative. It's not my CMS or project or idea, it's yours. I can think of a few ways, but if I were you, I'd start playing around with composer first.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from MJH (So i can close and not delete):
Develop them as composer packages. Then all you need to do is add it to your composer.json and composer update to have it working. You can even create some sort of UI for doing that if you dislike CLI. No need to invent your own JSON format, no need for.. well, anything really, you "just" need to develop actual business logic and let composer do the rest, it even supports versioning etc.